# How can i check if a twitch channel exists?

Tags: discord.js, twitch

Im trying to write a code that checks for twitch channels if they exist or not, i tried using request but the statusCode its allways 200

```
request(`https://www.twitch.tv/${args[1]}`, function(error, response, body){
    console.log('statusCode', response.statusCode)
```

edit: tried using twith api kraken but doesn't seem to work, if i use existing channels its the same response.

```
request('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + args[1], function(channel, response) {
    console.log(channel)
    if (channel == null) {
      return console.log("doesnt exists")
    } else {
      return console.log("Exists")
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status code of an HTML request is the status code of the request, not what was requested. 200 means that the request went through fine without problems.

You could either look through the response and body of the request or try the Kraken, which I'm not very familiar with. Have you looked through [the docs](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5)?

The docs [about this part](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/channels/#get-channel-by-id) use this syntax:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json' \
-H 'Client-ID: uo6dggojyb8d6soh92zknwmi5ej1q2' \
-X GET 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/44322889'
```

Your syntax probably works fine. The issue is probably that the response isn't null, but rather something like an empty object.

What response ARE you getting? What is your console output if you use `console.log(channel);
console.log(response);`

I hope I could help a bit.

Comment: Thanks!!, i fixed it by using twitch api, could not figure out how to use kraken ||

const tclient = await TwitchClient.withCredentials(clientId, accessToken);
const tuser = await tclient.helix.users.getUserByName(args[1]);
if (tuser === null) {
// ....
    } ||